# suggestion with this error ->ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1, 10)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a code that allows the user to enter 4 values (a, b, c, and d) for the equation (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d), then the program will output the graph on a window (I am using Tkinter). however, the code for some reason doesn't work.

To explain a bit my code in the input_check process I am outputting a button on a window with a blank box for the input. when the input is entered the program will check if it is the same as 3 (I will be adding more equations after (therefore it will check which equation the user wants), then it should asks for the values of a, b, c, and d, however after than it gives an error.

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()
root.title("Maths Plot")
root.geometry("600x500")
root.configure(bg='dark blue')


# this function is just for fun at the moment
def foo():
    print('working')

# navigation bar of the website
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

# file menu
file_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)

file_menu.add_command(label='notebook', command=foo)
file_menu.add_command(label='open', command=foo)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label='copy', command=foo)

# edit menu
edit_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=edit_menu)

edit_menu.add_command(label='add notebook', command=foo)
edit_menu.add_command(label='cell copy', command=foo)
edit_menu.add_separator()
edit_menu.add_command(label='paste cell', command=foo)


# checking which type of equation the user wants to enter on base of the number inputted
def input_check():
    processing = FALSE
    answer_int = int(answer1.get())
    while processing == FALSE:
        if answer_int == 1:
            confirmation = Label(root, text="You have inputted the number 1")
            confirmation.grid(row=3, column=1)
            execution = Button(root, text="execute", command=linear_equation())
            execution.grid(row=4, column=1)
            processing = TRUE
        elif answer_int == 2:
            confirmation = Label(root, text="You have inputted the number 2")
            confirmation.grid(row=3, column=1)
            execution = Button(root, text="execute", command=quadratic_equation())
            execution.grid(row=4, column=1)
            processing = TRUE

        elif answer_int == 3:
            confirmation = Label(root, text="You have inputted the number 3")
            confirmation.grid(row=3, column=1)
            execution = Button(root, text="execute", command=cubic_equation())
            execution.grid(row=4, column=1)
            processing = TRUE

        elif answer_int == 4:
            confirmation = Label(root, text="You have inputted the number 4")
            confirmation.grid(row=3, column=1)
            execution = Button(root, text="execute", command=exponential_equation())
            execution.grid(row=4, column=1)
            processing = TRUE
        else:
            confirmation = Label(root, text="the answer you inputted is invalid, please try again.")
            confirmation.grid(row=3, column=1)


label1 = Label(root, text="enter a number between 1 and 4 ")
answer1 = Entry(root)
button1 = Button(root, text='enter', command=input_check)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
answer1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)


def linear_equation():
    print("this is function 1")


def quadratic_equation():
    print("this is function 2")


def cubic_equation():
    a = ''
    b = ''
    c = ''
    d = ''

    # converting the Entries from string to float for future calcuations
    def enter_click(event):
        global a
        global b
        global c
        global d
        a = float(a_entry.get())
        b = float(b_entry.get())
        c = float(c_entry.get())
        d = float(d_entry.get())

        # code
        x_axis = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=100)

        y_base = [a * x_axis ** 3 + b * x_axis ** 2 + c * x_axis + d]

        plt.figure(num=0, dpi=120)
        plt.plot(x_axis, y_base, label="f(x)", linestyle='--')
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(linestyle=':')
        plt.xlim([-1000, 1000])
        plt.ylim([-1000, 1000])

        plt.title('graph')
        plt.xlabel('x-axis')
        plt.ylabel('y-axis')

    a_entry = Entry(root)
    a_entry.grid(row=5, column=0)
    b_entry = Entry(root)
    b_entry.grid(row=6, column=0)
    c_entry = Entry(root)
    c_entry.grid(row=7, column=0)
    d_entry = Entry(root)
    d_entry.grid(row=8, column=0)

    enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter")
    enter_button.grid(row=9, column=0)
    enter_button.bind("<Button-1>", enter_click)
    enter_button.bind("<Return>", enter_click)

    '''def cubic():
        return a * x_axis ** 3 + b * x_axis ** 2 + c * x_axis + d'''


def exponential_equation():
    print("this is function 4")


root.mainloop()
```

the error that I keep getting is:
 `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1, 10)`
I tried to search online for any information but I didn't find anything usefull.
(I found some solutions that use canvas but I have no idea on how to use it).

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: This error is produced by `plt.plot()` and refers to the first two arguments, `x` and `y`. In OP's code these are `x_axis` (the result of a call to `numpy.linspace()` which returns an array of length 1000 with values from -10 to 10) and `y_base` (assigned inside a while loop that appears to have either zero or infinite iterations, depending on whether `last_item < 11` is True). `last_item` appears to be set to the final value (as int) of `x_axis`, which looks like 10. So the while loop should be infinite and `plt.plot()` should never be reached. @Balpreet, is your code complete?

Comment: @constantstranger this is the main part of the code (this section should do all the calculations required to plot an equation ), other than this code I just need to build the interface for the user

Comment: @constantstranger I made some changes to the code. I moved all the plotting code, inside the enter_click procedure (for some reason I wasn't able to use the values of a,b,c, and d outside of the procedure even if I defined them as global). Then I removed the while loop for the y_base and put square brackets around the calculations. However, even if I made this change the same error appears

Comment: I found that I had to change the brackets (from square to the normal round once) of the line where I calculate y_base. And now the code work.
Thanks, everyone for the help.

Comment: @Balpreet it's true that square brackets would have been making `y_base` into a list with a single element that is an array of length 10, hence the error message indicating a shape of (1, 10) instead of the desired (10,). Not sure you would even need the round brackets - have you tried using no brackets at all on the right-hand side of the `y_base` assignment?

Comment: @constantstranger if I remove the round brakets it dosn't work